# Merging different columns with the same name into single columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I having a `data.frame` in which some columns have the same Name. Now I want to merge/add up these columns into single columns. So for example I want to turn....

```
v1 v1 v1 v2 v2 
 1  0  2  4  1
 3  1  1  1  0
```

...into...

```
v1  v2
 3   5  
 5   1
```

---

I only found threads dealing with two `data.frame`s supposed to be merged into one but none dealing with this (rather simple?) problem.

---

The data can be recreated with this:

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 3L), v1 = 0:1, v1 = c(2L, 1L), 
                v2 = c(4L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 0L)), 
               .Names = c("v1", "v1", "v1", "v2", "v2"),  
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Agree with @Thomas, in this case I was able to re-create your data table with `read.table`, but it would have been better if you had `dput`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it works now. Next time I will of course try to deliver a reproducible example!

Answer (score 2):

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(x) Reduce(`+`, x)))
```

produces:

```
  v1 v2
1  3  5
2  5  1
```

`split.default(...)` breaks up the data frame into groups with equal column names, then we use `Reduce` on each of those groups to sum the values of each column in the group iteratively until there is only one column left per group (see `?Reduce`, that is what the function does), and finally we convert back to data frame with `as.data.frame`.

We have to use `split.default` because `split` (or really, `split.data.frame`, which it will dispatch) splits on rows, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2". Since there's no "id" variable, I've used `melt(as.matrix(df))` instead of `melt(df, id.vars="id")`. This automatically creates a long version of your data that has "Var1" as representing your `rownames` and "Var2" as your `colnames`. Using that knowledge, you can do:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(as.matrix(df)), Var1 ~ Var2, 
      value.var = "value", fun.aggregate=sum)
#   Var1 v1 v2
# 1    1  3  5
# 2    2  5  1
```